# Proper way to de-serialize a property of type collection of abstract object in Asp.net Core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction. I am trying to create a Web API using Asp.net core, but I don't know how to implement the conversion of property whose type is a `List` of object derived from an abstract class.

Here is the content of my `Program.cs`, which makes it apparent that I am just using the basic template provided by Visual Studio:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ObjectToPassDataContext>(o =>
{
    o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

These are my models:

```
public abstract class BaseA
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedA: BaseA
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedB: BaseA
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectToPass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BaseA> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

And in one of the controllers (which was generated using visual studio controller template), I have a post action that does the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ObjectToPass>> PostObjectToPass(ObjectToPass objectToPass)
{
    if (_context.ObjectsToPass == null)
    {
        return Problem("Entity set is null.");
    }
    _context.ObjectsToPass.Add(objectToPass);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("ObjectToPass", new { Name = questionBank.Name }, objectToPass);
}
```

here is a sample request body:

```
{
  "name": "sample Name",
  "collection": [
    {
      "name": "sample name",
       /* here's where I am lost, because i dont know how to tell the deserializer what type will this object be converted to, like if I add Prop1 parameter, was hoping it is able to recognize it as type DerivedA */
    }
  ]
}
```

the post command above would obviously fail if executed, since the the type `BaseA` has no public parameter-less constructor.

I have tried looking into json custom converter and ModelBinder but I don't know how to implement it.

Note:

- It may not matter in this case, but I'm using Entityframework core, and the `_context` in the Post command is just the DBContext:`ObjectToPassDataContext` injected on the `Program.cs`. the `ObjectToPassDataContext` also has a DBset named `ObjectsToPass`.
- My targetframework is Net6.0

Comment: this might help for the converter. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization

Comment: @Firo thanks, so basically I'll just have to enforce and discriminator parameter in the json to distinguish the derived type, my concern now is how to make the loop through the objects in the list of the json.

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of this

```
public class ObjectToPass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(BaseAListConverter))]
    public List<BaseA> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class BaseAListConverter : JsonConverter<List<BaseA>>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(Person).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override List<BaseA> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            throw new JsonException();

        var result = new List<BaseA>();
        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                throw new JsonException();

            string propertyName = reader.GetString();
            if (propertyName != "TypeName")
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }

            reader.Read();
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.String)
                throw new JsonException();

            string discriminator = reader.GetString();
            Type objType = Type.GetType(typeof(BaseA).Namespace + "." + discriminator);
            if (objType == null)
                throw new JsonException("unknown " + discriminator);
            BaseA obj = (BaseA)Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                    return obj;

                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                {
                    propertyName = reader.GetString();
                    reader.Read();
                    var prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);
                    if (prop != null)
                    {
                        object value = prop.PropertyType switch
                        {
                            string => reader.GetString(),
                            decimal => reader.GetDecimal(),
                            ...
                        }
                        prop.SetValue(obj, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            throw new JsonException();
        return result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<BaseA> baseobjects, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var baseobj in baseobjects)
        {
            Type type = baseobj.GetType();
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WriteString("TypeName", type.Name);

            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    writer.WriteString(prop.Name, (string)prop.GetValue(baseobj));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
                    writer.WriteNumber(prop.Name, (decimal)prop.GetValue(baseobj));
                ...
            }

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```